# How to break from List<T>.AsParallel().ForAll() using C#

Tags: c#-4.0, plinq

I am using List.AsParallel().ForAll() PLINQ implementation. Inside the loop, if I find a condition is successful, I want the loop to break immediately out of the ForAll() loop. How can I achieve it?

Here is the sample code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Basics
{
class Program
{
    class Family
    {
        public int SNo { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    static List<Family> families = null;
    static Program()
    {
        families = new List<Family>()
        {
            new Family(){SNo = 10, Name="Richard"},
            new Family(){SNo = 33, Name="Xio Fung"},
            new Family(){SNo = 10, Name="Sean"},
            new Family(){SNo = 10, Name="Andrea"},
            new Family(){SNo = 20, Name="Bjorn"},
            new Family(){SNo = 20, Name="Isabella"},
            new Family(){SNo = 35, Name="Michael"},
            new Family(){SNo = 35, Name="Marie"}
        };
    }

    private static void Main()
    {
        Dictionary<int, List<Family>> theFamily = new Dictionary<int, List<Family>>();
        var groupedFamilies = families.GroupBy(family => family.SNo);

        groupedFamilies.AsParallel().ForAll(groupedFamily =>
        {
            int groupedFamilyCount = groupedFamily.Count();
            if (groupedFamilyCount == 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(groupedFamily.FirstOrDefault().Name);     
                // break; <-- I want to break if I find the count = 1
            }
        });                                 
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Regards,
Sriram

Comment: Throw that part of it into its own method and `return` ?

Comment: My intension is to come out of the ForAll() as soon as the condition satisfies. I would like to know to break from the loop in parallel scearnio.

Comment: By the way, the `theFamily` dictionary isn't being used in your sample. Also, you should not try to access `Name` after `FirstOrDefault` without checking for null first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe `Parallel.ForEach` will work:

```
Parallel.ForEach(groupedFamilies.AsParallel(), (groupedFamily, loopState) =>
            {
                int groupedFamilyCount = groupedFamily.Count();
                if (groupedFamilyCount == 1)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(groupedFamily.FirstOrDefault().Name);
                    loopState.Stop(); // break if I find the count = 1

                }
            });
```

Depending on your use case, you might need `loopState.Break` instead. Use `Stop()` for Any-like operations, `Break()` for First-like ones.

There's a good article on the subject in Microsoft's [articles on parallel programming with .NET 4](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12594) called "When To Use Parallel For Each Or PLINQ?"

Comment: Is it not possible with List<T>.AsParallel().ForAll() ? I am sure the Parallel.ForEach() will do. But I am trying to find out if the same is achievable with the former!

Comment: No, the article I mentioned explains why. Basically, the extra loop control you gain from this overload of `ForEach` can't always be translated by LINQ to other languages.

Comment: Yeah. I agree with you!